# Move adjacent text boxes when current text box grows

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to create a windows form with multiple text boxes and these text boxes can grow/shrink. i would like to move the text boxes to its right and below it, based on the text entered in the current text box.

I am growing the current text box using below code

```
 protected void Txtbx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox Txtbx = sender as TextBox;
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Txtbx.Text, Txtbx.Font);
        Txtbx.Width = size.Width;
        Txtbx.Height = size.Height + 20;
    }
```

FYI I am using a panel to hold the text boxes in each row and grow property set on panel.

[image: Before the text is entered]

Above image is text boxes before the text is entered

[image: After Entering text in textbox1]

Above image is after entering text in textbox.

As you can see current text box is taking over other textboxes ,is there an easy way to move them.

All the text boxes are generated dynamically,so I was planning to adjust the location of other text boxes based on current text box in the same textchanged event handler but i feel its overkill.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Yep that worked. 
when i posted the question, i was thinking FlowLayoutPanel is either topdown or lefttoright but just realized i could use two FlowLayoutPanel. one FlowLayoutPanel with topdown and inside it create FlowLayoutPanel for each row.

Comment: Alignment of columns  is not working (i.e. lets say i change cell 1 of row 1 then cell 2 is moving but cell 2 of row 2 not moving). any other suggestion?

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: First thing i tried was TableLayoutpanel but it wasn't growing.

Just now,instead of dynamic i tried to create panel manually and add 4 textboxes into cell(0,0),cell(0,1),cell(1,0),cell(1,1) and set the following
1.Size type to autosize on all columns and rows
2.Autosize property set to true
3.AutosizeMode property set to GrowAndShrink.
4.Anchor position on all of them to "Top, Bottom, Left, Right"
Still not working,am i missing something?

Comment: I had to increase height and width of textbox inside the textbox textchanged event handler to make textbox grow and that made the tablelayoutpanel grow